# Prevent showing the button if input value was changed but than changed back to default value

Tags: jquery

I've set up my simplified code snippet to help you understand my question.

The code's condition adds the class name on **any** input value change. **My goal** is to prevent showing the update button if the input value was changed but than changed back to default value in our case the value "1".

```js
// Bind an action on input change event
$( "#quantity" ).on('input',function(e){

  // Following happens if the value is not equal to 1
  if($("#quantity").val() != "1"){

    // Show the update button
    $( "#update" ).addClass( "show" );

  }

});
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
.show{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1">

<button id="update" type="submit" class="hide">Update</button>
```

Comment: so you want to show the button if value is changed to default value ... in above case 1 ?? what is your issue?

Comment: You just need to add an `else` clause to switch the class back to `hide`.

Comment: I don't want to show the button If a value is changed back to default value. Or in other words show it only if value is changed @KarthikGanesan

Comment: check this link https://jsfiddle.net/bb085grp/3/ @DominikK

Comment: Yes, this is the desired output @KarthikGanesan. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @mrogers I thought that else clause wasn't necessary when the statement was passing false. But I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `else` clause in your function to change the class back to `hide`.  Also added a `removeClass` to the first part of the function.

```js
// Bind an action on input change event
$( "#quantity" ).on('input',function(e){

  // Following happens if the value is not equal to 1
  if($("#quantity").val() != "1"){

    // Show the update button
    $( "#update" ).removeClass( "hide" );
    $( "#update" ).addClass( "show" );

  } else {

    // Show the update button
    $( "#update" ).removeClass( "show" );
    $( "#update" ).addClass( "hide" );
  }

});
```

```css
.hide{display:none}
.show{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1">

<button id="update" type="submit" class="hide">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quantity").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if ($("#quantity").val() === "1") {
      $("#update").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("#update").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    }
  });
})
```

here is the js fiddle for it

https://jsfiddle.net/bb085grp/4/